# What is the role of the art curator?

Tags: reference-request, aesthetics

I keep seeing people talking about the increased importance of curation in art today.

What is going on here, has any philosopher discussed this trend or possible problems linked to curation of art? Especially in relation to the internet.

Comment: Is there any chance you might be able to spell out a little more clearly the specific problem you're encountering in your reading/study?

Comment: @JosephWeissman the specific problem is that i don't know anywhere which talks about this

Comment: Curation is an important concept in aesthetics; in Benjamin it fits into the notion of the aura of the artwork; there is also a movement that rejects institutionalised curation looking to curate art in the world - for example, graffiti art or art provera; in a way it returns to an earlier concept of art, before the gallery and museum held sway; I don't, unfortunately know enough, to give specifics such as names of philosophers or aestheticians that go into this in more detail. So a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: This may just need reframing as a reference request

Answer (score 1):

There are several interesting documentaries that deal with this topic of art appreciation vs art curation. "My Kid Could Paint That" directed by Amir Bar-Lev and "Who the *$&% Is Jackson Pollock?" directed by Harry Moses both deal with the incongruence of art value as an intrinsic quality of art versus a value determined by the curator and "high art community". This is not a new trend, as its much the same in classical art patron who supports and commissions art. I think the difference is a change in society. We are less divided in a socially enforced aristocracy. Instead we are increasingly using economics to define this division. Thus, we have professionalized this divid using curators.

Additionally, the availability of social media and internet access has made it so that art can be disseminated by and to the mass public. As a somewhat opposing force, there are communities that employ credentialism in order to create a qualitative differentiation, and this relies on the institutionalization of curating.